# How to configure Django and G Suite for SMTP

Tags: django, email, google-workspace, django-settings, django-email

When the user is registering on my website an E-Mail is sent to the user to confirm his/her E-Mail.
It works with this settings:

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'myemail@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'abcdefghiklmnopq'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
```

Now I want to switch to noreply@mydomain.com.
I created an account on G Suite and made the following configurations:

> **Comprehensive mail storage** (Locally applied) 
>  Ensure that a copy of all
>   sent and received mail is stored in associated users' mailboxes: ON
>
> **SMTP relay service** (Locally applied)  
> ms_mail 
> Allowed senders: Only
>   addresses in my domains 
> Only accept mail from the specified IP
>   addresses: No 
> Require SMTP Authentication: Yes 
> Require TLS encryption:
>   Yes
>
> **Less secure apps** (Locally applied) 
>  Allow Users to manage their access to less secure apps
>   Less Secure Apps
>
> Allow less secure apps: ON

Than I created an App Password an tried a lot of configurations like this:

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp-relay.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'noreply@mydomain.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'abcdefghiklmnopq'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'noreply@mydomain.com'
SERVER_EMAIL = 'noreply@mydomain.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 465
```

I can't find a good documentation on Google or Django how to configure the settings. Does anybody now a good resource? Is the App Password/Less secure Apps the right way to do it? Because Google has some security warnings. Noreply is a group but I created the app password for my.name@mydomain.com. Is this a problem when I am part of the group? I also tried several options with my.name@mydomain.com instead of noreply@mydomain.com but I always get the error

```
smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected: Connection unexpectedly closed
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this in your settings.py

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'noreply@mydomain.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '#########'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
```

Comment: this isn't working for me unfortunately. Any alternative?

Comment: @Marco what type of error are you facing with this?